# Select records comparing a field from another table

Tags: php, mysql, loops, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I have three tables

1. orders
2. members
3. products

In orders, I have fields `id, mem_id, date, prod_id, status` where mem_id coming from `members` table and prod_id is coming from `products` table

In members, I have fields `mem_id, name, phone, address, city, state, zip, country` where country holds id of country from `country` table

Now, I want to show the records from `orders` table only for product id 2 and from `members` from country id 25

I have tried doing:

```
SELECT o.mem_id, o.prod_id, m.mem_id FROM orders o INNER JOIN members m ON m.mem_id = (SELECT mem_id FROM members WHERE country=25) WHERE o.prod_id=2
```

But it gives:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in
```

So, its not fetching any data and a problem in my query. Please suggest me, Thanks

Comment: SELECT o.mem_id, o.prod_id, m.mem_id FROM orders o 
  INNER JOIN members m ON m.mem_id = o.mem_id WHERE o.prod_id=2 and  m.country=25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table using `ON condition` and apply the `where condition` like this

```
SELECT o.mem_id, o.prod_id, m.mem_id
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN members m 
ON m.mem_id = o.mem_id 
WHERE o.prod_id=2 and  m.country=25
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I see where I was making mistake.

Comment: glad to help you @Hashmi

Comment: I have a question though ... can I also do a count(*) in such scenario?

Comment: yeah you can @Hashmi

Comment: Since I am showing records in ajax pagination, so I doing { SELECT count(*) FROM orders o INNER JOIN members m ON m.mem_id = o.mem_id WHERE o.prod_id=2 and m.country=25 } to get get total rows, but it is not working properly and all records are showing on one page only.

Comment: it's look new problem . create new question with clear explanation. @Hashmi

Comment: I can post once in 90 minutes :( I will try to post later and comment with question link here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the tables on column and specify the condition in `WHERE` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT o.mem_id, o.prod_id, m.mem_id
FROM orders o JOIN members m ON o.mem_id = m.men_id
WHERE o.prod_id = 2 AND m.country = 25;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I see where I was making mistake.